# How to setup multiple schemas in SearchPath parameter with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core

I have 2 schemas in Postgres, "development-app-service" and "extensions".
Postgres documentation states that I should be able to keep extensions in a separate schema ("extensions") if I add it to the search path.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I added this to my connection string `;SearchPath=development-app-service,extensions;` - but extensions still cannot be found.

If I move extensions to "development-app-service" schema it works, but in that case I have to reference extension by schema name, making it tightly coupled.

Is there any way to accomplish this in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Why not just change the search path for the the DB user using `alter user`? Then you only need to do this once and not worry about it in the application

Comment: He have the same db user with access to multiple schemas. In our case we can only setup connection from backend side. For example, regarding of environment, backend should use different set of schemas